# Plotting x-axis in MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot

The following variables are used:

- `SP`: a known 8x1 row Vector containing random numbers.
- `YP`: a known 8x1 row Vector containing random numbers.

I have eight data points. For every 8 data points on x-axis, I have the following labels:

Asset1 - Asset2 -  Asset3  - Asset4 -  Asset5  - Asset6 -  Asset7  - Asset8

**Problem: when I implement my code, I get an infinite number of the above labels.**

This is my output from MatLab:

[image: my output]

This is my code:

```
SP = rand(8,1)/100;
YP = (rand(8,1)/100)*2;
plot(YP,'DisplayName','YP');
hold on;
plot(SP,'DisplayName','SP');
hold off;
title('SP and YP monthly returns');
xlabel('Monthly time series');
MY = 'Siemens SAP Daimler Allianz DEU.Telekom Adidas BMW DEU.Bank';
set(gca, 'xTickLabels', 'Asset1 Asset2 Asset3 Asset4 Asset5 Asset6 Asset7 Asset8');
xticklabel_rotate('Asset1 Asset2 Asset3 Asset4 Asset5 Asset6 Asset7 Asset8');
ylabel('Percentage of prices discounts');
set(gca, 'yTickLabels', num2str(100.*get(gca,'yTick')','%g%%'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [cell array of character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html) for [`'XTickLabel'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51535), not a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html):

```
labelCell = {'Asset1' 'Asset2' 'Asset3' 'Asset4' 'Asset5' 'Asset6' 'Asset7' 'Asset8'};
set(gca, 'xTickLabel', labelCell);
```

When you pass a character array like you did, MATLAB just recycles the whole thing for every tick label. You'll have to pass a cell array to [`xticklabel_rotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate) as well if you still want to rotate the labels. However, newer versions of MATLAB allow you to do this by modifying the [`'XTickLabelRotation'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e52699) property:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);  % Rotate by 45 degrees
```