# Labeling a string on x-axis vertically in MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot

The following variables are used:

- `SP`: a known 196x1 row Vector containing random numbers.
- `YP`: a known 196x1 row Vector containing random numbers.
- `Names`: a known 196x1 a column string containing 196 names.

The issue is within the x-axis. The array of `Names` in reality contain from "Jan 2000 Feb, 2000, March 2000,..., Dec 2016." Since I cannot simulate these 196 months here, I just created 196 names with a "for" function in the my code (please see the coding section).

**Problem: My output from the MatLab only takes the first nine values of `Names` string. I want all 196 data in `Names` string to be posted vertically on the x-axis.**

This is my output from the MatLab (See x-axis):

[image: undesired output from MatLab]

This is how I want my output to look like:

[image: desired output from MatLab]

Here is my code:

```
%define variables
SP = rand(196,1)/100;
YP = (rand(196,1)/100)*2;
%plotting two vectors of SP and YP
plot(YP,'DisplayName','YP');
hold on;
plot(SP,'DisplayName','SP');
hold off;
title('SP and YP monthly returns');
%This is x-axis with creating a string of 196x1 dimensions
xlabel('Monthly time series');
for i=1:196
Names(i,:)='Sample Text'
end
set(gca, 'xTickLabels', Names); 
%y-axis
ylabel('Percentage of prices discounts');
set(gca, 'yTickLabels', num2str(100.*get(gca,'yTick')','%g%%'));
```

Comment: Label rotation is in [Gnovice's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43898971/2748311) to your question from an hour ago.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832722/how-to-post-month-year-to-x-axis-and-percentage-to-y-axis) that you have deleted now? And as excaza noted, you have already asked about the label rotation in [your post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43898971/2748311) about an hour ago. Both of these questions were also asked by you in your deleted post

Comment: @excaza thanks for the linking back, but I could not figure it out based on the last problem. Thanks to the below asnwer, my problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when data is plotted you have **only** 11 xtick in x-axis so when you change their names it's normal you have 11 xtick so you can check below code

```
%define variables
SP = rand(196,1)/100;
YP = (rand(196,1)/100)*2;
%plotting two vectors of SP and YP
plot(YP,'DisplayName','YP');
hold on;
plot(SP,'DisplayName','SP');
hold off;
title('SP and YP monthly returns');
%This is x-axis with creating a string of 196x1 dimensions
xlabel('Monthly time series');

xTicks=1:5:196;            % EDITED 
                           % number of xticklabel control by xticks variable
set(gca,'xTick',xTicks);   % EDITED

for i=1:196
  Names(i,:)='Sample Text';
end
set(gca, 'xTickLabels', Names);
rotateXLabels(gca,90); %for using this command you must download it or if % 
                       %your matlab version is 2015 or higher you have this 
                       %function in your toolbox
```

output for 1:5:196 is like below picture [image]